# How can I create a theme for a Google Docs Presentation?

Tags: google-drive

Does Google Docs allow you to create new themes for Presentations. I can change the background and set text colours for each part but how/can these be set for the whole presentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few ways to do this, none of which are perfect:

- **Apply background to all**. Go to the Format menu, select "Change Background", select your background, then choose Apply background to all slides. Unfortunately there isn't an equivalent for text colours.
- **Choose from an existing theme from within an existing presentation** - these are a bit limited, but at least do apply background, font, colour etc across all slides.
- **Choose from an existing theme when creating a new presentation** - there are a load of templates set up when you go to "Create New" -> "From Template" - maybe you can find one there that suits?
- **Make your own theme** - you could make your own theme if you follow this: [Template submissions: Submitting a template](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=148817) *This works only if you have a paid Google Apps account.  I believe that you can also create templates with public @gmail.com accounts, but these will be open to the public*

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I hadn't seen the 'Submit template' on the doc list page although it looks like you can only submit templates to the public gallery. As you say none are perfect but I'll work with this.

Comment: If you have a Google Apps account, I believe you can add Templates to a gallery just for your domain.

Comment: As of 2016, you can also use `Slide > Edit Master` to make modifications to the current them (of which there are several you can start from.) I still haven't found a way to create a *new* theme.